# NFS mount on client not matching what's exported on the server

Tags: networking, filesystems, mount, nfs, ecryptfs

I've managed to successfully network two home computers with a crossover Ethernet cable. My intention is to arrange a fast transfer of files from one to the other. This is the first time I'm pairing the two computers together.

The folder on the server computer has also been successfully mounted on the client computer via NFS. My problem is that, from the client, I can browse the files/folders on the server, only that some of those files/folders were deleted years ago on the server, and some files/folders present on the server are not at all showing up on the client.

It's not clear to me how the client managed to unearth files/folders that were deleted on the server as far back as 2017, but what I'd like right now is for the mount on the client to match the exposed directory on the server.

My server `/etc/exports`:

```
/home   192.168.1.2(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,crossmnt)
```

The result of executing `lsblk`:

```
NAME                           MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                              8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk  
├─sda1                           8:1    0   243M  0 part  /boot
├─sda2                           8:2    0     1K  0 part  
└─sda5                           8:5    0 931.3G  0 part  
  └─sda5_crypt (dm-0)          252:0    0 931.3G  0 crypt 
    ├─ubuntu--vg-root (dm-1)   252:1    0 923.3G  0 lvm   /
    └─ubuntu--vg-swap_1 (dm-2) 252:2    0   7.9G  0 lvm   
sr0                             11:0    1  1024M  0 rom   
loop0                            7:0    0  24.5M  1 loop  /snap/heroku/3766
loop1                            7:1    0    25M  1 loop  /snap/heroku/3762
loop2                            7:2    0  24.5M  1 loop  /snap/heroku/3768
loop3                            7:3    0  89.4M  1 loop  /snap/core/6818
loop4                            7:4    0  88.4M  1 loop  /snap/core/6964
loop5                            7:5    0  89.3M  1 loop  /snap/core/6673
```

And executing `mount` returns:

```
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu type cgroup (rw,relatime,cpu)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuacct type cgroup (rw,relatime,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,relatime,hugetlb)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext2 (rw)
rpc_pipefs on /run/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/heroku_3766.snap on /snap/heroku/3766 type squashfs (ro,nodev)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/heroku_3762.snap on /snap/heroku/3762 type squashfs (ro,nodev)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/heroku_3768.snap on /snap/heroku/3768 type squashfs (ro,nodev)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_6818.snap on /snap/core/6818 type squashfs (ro,nodev)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_6964.snap on /snap/core/6964 type squashfs (ro,nodev)
/var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_6673.snap on /snap/core/6673 type squashfs (ro,nodev)
/home/zeus/.Private on /home/zeus type ecryptfs (ecryptfs_check_dev_ruid,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=16,ecryptfs_unlink_sigs,ecryptfs_sig=f51524d82e452e8a,ecryptfs_fnek_sig=0c150644544e4e15)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=zeus)
nfsd on /proc/fs/nfsd type nfsd (rw)
```

Comment: I guess you have overmounted a sub directory of your NFS export. The NFS server by default does not export multiple file systems beneath an export root and therefore you see the old data. You could try adding `crossmnt` to your NFS server `/etc/exports` line, then do a `exportfs -ar` to pick up the changes and remount on the client.

Comment: But I'm trying to mount on the client the `/home` directory on the server. I've followed your instructions about adding the `crossmnt` but no difference. No error is being returned.

Comment: You should add the contents of `/etc/exports` and the output of `lsblk` or `mount` on the NFS server to your question.

Comment: I've added the necessary edits to the question. Please check and advise. If I'm not doing things that should be obvious, do bear with me since I'm no sysadmin -- just a Java developer with not much operations expertise.

Comment: I've noticed that you've added the `ecryptfs` tag. Does that mean that the `/home` directory being encrypted on the server has something to do with my NFS setup not working as expected?

Comment: `/home/zeus` is a ecryptfs and I guess you refer to that directory? I am not experienced with ecryptfs but read that it causes trouble when exporting over NFS.

Comment: I see. Anyway, the server computer is a system running Ubuntu 14.04. What I actually want to do is backup the files on it to the client computer, then upgrade the server computer to Ubuntu 18.04. I have that Ethernet connection working, but apparently NFS is a dead end. I've tried to `scp` the `/home` directory on the server to the client via SSH, but with terabytes of data to transfer, too slow. So what other options do I have?

Comment: Best would be to leave this thread behind and open a new question with what you actually want to achieve.